# A simple question about regex usage in list

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list in list as ''list_all'' below, I am looking for a word as stated 'c' below. Ther is no 'c' in second list. Codes below give results as ['c', 'c'] but I want to have ['c', '', 'c'] as to be same lenght 'list_all'. Could you please help me on it how can I put empty element to result.

```
import re

    list_all = [['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','d'],['a','b','c','d','e']]
    
    listofresult =[]
    for h in [*range(len(list_all))]:
        for item in list_all[h]:
            patern = r"(c)"
            if re.search(patern, item):
                listofresult.append(item)
            else:
                None
    
    print(listofresult)
```

Comment: Why are you using a regex? All you need is `['c' if 'c' in x else '' for x in list_all]`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/PL0tO2).

Comment: Because in normal codes it like '' a bla bla '' , 'b bla bla' . Starting of the sentences are same but continues different , do you have any recommadation?

Comment: If you could provide a bit more real-life sample it would be helpful. Maybe you want something like https://ideone.com/IJ1aHl?

Comment: I am scrapping product specs some of them has model code some of them not. And codes does not resemble each other the only common thing is  starting 'model code' . So the list looks like ''list_all = [['a  blabla','b bla','c bla','d12'],['a  bl','b bl','d bl'],['a blsl','b bls ','c bla','d bla ','e blas']] '''    that why I have to use regex.

Comment: Ok, at any rate, look at your code: `if re.search(patern, item): listofresult.append(item) else: None`. You just issue None upon no match. You need `listofresult.append('')` in the `else` branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
import re

list_all = [['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','d'],['a','b','c','d','e']]

temp = True
listofresult =[]
for h in range(len(list_all)):
    for item in list_all[h]:
        patern = r"(c)"
        if re.search(patern, item):
            listofresult.append(item)
            temp = False
    if temp:
        listofresult.append("")
    temp = True

print(listofresult)
```

Comment: if in each list in list there is more than 1 'c', and you only want to take one 'c', add `break` after `temp = False`

Comment: Thanks al lot it works fine, if you tell me the logic briefly I will be more than appreciated.

Comment: You need the temp variable to find out if the program has found 'c', if it hasn't found 'c' it will append an empty string

Answer (score 1):

That's an unusual use of regex! but if you insist, this correction might help:

```python
import re

list_all = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]

list_of_result = []
for h in list_all:
    result = ''
    for item in h:
        pattern = r"(c)"
        if re.search(pattern, item):
            result = item
            break
    if result:
        list_of_result.append(result)
    else:
        list_of_result.append('')

print(list_of_result)
```

Comment: yes to be honest the usage in my codes is little bit different, I have to use regex, thanks for your help it works very well.